# How do I instantiate a child class in a default method of an immutable abstract base class?

Tags: oop, dart, design-patterns

How do I instantiate a child class in a default method of an immutable abstract base class e.g. return a new instance with modified properties?

I have an abstract document class with a few properties which is immutable.
When calling the createDocument or updateDocument methods, a new instance should be returned with the fields set to the new values. I don't want to override the methods in each child class since the logic will remain the same => duplicate code. Is there a way / pattern to get around this problem or am i simply missing something here?

```
abstract class Document extends Model {
    final Version version;
    final Id id;
    final DateTime createdAt;
    final DateTime modifiedAt;

    Document(this.version, {this.id, this.createdAt, this.modifiedAt})

    Document createDocument(Id id, DateTime timestamp) {
        // some validation logic here
        // TODO 
        // Instantiate a class of the same type that extends document (e.g. user in this example) and set the id, createdAt fields 
    }

    Document updateDocument(DateTime timestamp) {
        // some validation logic here
        // TODO 
        // Instantiate a class of the same type that extends document (e.g. user in this example) and set modified at field
    }
}

class User extends Document {
    static const Version VERSION = Version(1,0,0);
    final int someProperty;
    User(this.someProperty) : super(VERSION)

}
```

One idea of mine was to implement an abstract copyWith method

```
  Document copyWith({Id id, DateTime modifiedAt, DateTime createdAt});
```

but that would mean that other classes can access the copy method and set arbitrary values which would defeat the whole purpose of the validation logic in the methods and it would inflate the code. Furthermore since I'm using Dart I can not really use protected methods.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You cannot create an instance of `Document` because it's an abstract class.

Comment: I've removed the `java` tag since this doesn't seem to have anything to do with Java and the `immutability` tag since this doesn't seem directly related to the base class being immutable.

Comment: Hi marc, yes I am aware that I cannot create an instance of Document. The child class which extends Document should be instantiated. I guess I formulated that incorrectly here.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a virtual private copy function:

```dart
abstract class Document extends Model {
    final Version version;
    final Id id;
    final DateTime createdAt;
    final DateTime modifiedAt;

    Document(this.version, {this.id, this.createdAt, this.modifiedAt})

    Document _copy({Id id, DateTime createdAt, DateTime modifiedAt});

    Document createDocument(Id id, DateTime timestamp) =>
      _copy(id: id, createdAt: timestamp);

    Document updateDocument(DateTime timestamp) {
       // some validation logic here
       return _copy(modifiedAt: timestamp);
    }
}

class User extends Document {
    static const Version VERSION = Version(1,0,0);
    final int someProperty;
    User(this.someProperty) : super(VERSION)

    User._(Version version, 
      {Id id, DateTime createdAt, DateTime modifiedAt, this.someProperty}) 
        : super(version, id: id, createdAt createdAt, modifiedAt: modifiedAt);
      
    User _copy({Id id, DateTime createdAt, DateTime modifiedAt, int someProperty}) =>
      User._(version,
          id: id ?? this.id, 
          createdAt: createdAt ?? this.createdAt,
          modifiedAt : modifiedAt ?? this.modifiedAt, 
          someProperty: someProperty ?? this.someProperty);
}
```

This should ensure that only you can call the private helper methods which creates objects without validation, and that your `createDocument` method will work with any of your subclasses (as long as it faithfully implements `_copy`).

It does mean that you have to declare all the classes in the same library.